# Query parent domain from sub domain for non/authoritative names

Tags: recursion, dns, subdomain, bind

This question/scenario confuses me a lot. Please help!

Let's say we have 3 DNS servers - A,B, and C.
A: cache server; it servers recursive lookup for dns names on the Internet.
B: Master DNS server which serves example.com
C: Master DNS server which servers sub.example.com <- sub domain name server of example.com

B has a [forward only] statement, and [forwarders] statement contains of A's IP.
 
B has [recursive] set to 'no'. 
For non authoritative queries, such as google.com, the request comes from B and goes to A. 
The server A responds to B with google.com IP address.

C does not have example.com zone and it forward all traffic to A. 
I think the query for example.com goes to A, and A responds to B with example.com. 
Since, B has a [forwards only] statement and it has [A's IP address] as [forwarders] statement list. 
B has [recursion] set to 'no'

Question is ... What would happen if C tries to lookup google.com's IP address?
If C does not get response for google.com from B then what should I do? Please give me your advice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C should never do that.

Authoritative name servers, like B and C in your example, should only ever respond to queries for the zones for which they are authoritative. For *any* other query, they should answer `REFUSED` or `SERVFAIL`. This is both for security reasons (you don't want your servers abused for DDoS attacks) and for the admin's sanity. From this follows that authoritative servers should never send out queries of their own, they only respond to ones they are sent. So, in your case, both B and C should refuse to answer when asked about `google.com`.

Recursing servers, like A in your example, are the ones that go out and send queries to other servers. A should respond to a query for `google.com` by recursing down from the root in the normal fashion.

Another thing that follows from this is that other processes running on B and C cannot use the local name server daemon for name resolution (since they'll only answer for their auth zones). So on B and C, `resolv.conf` should point at server A. If their queries are for `example.com` or `sub.example.com` A will then go back and query the auth servers on B or C, so it can respond to the original query.

(All this assumes, of course, that you're not doing split horizon or some other more complicated setup, but even then it makes things more understandable if you can clearly separate authoritative and resolving servers.)

Does that make things clearer for you?

Comment: Based on the answer you provided, should all client utilizes A as their primary DNS server and A should have his [root.hint] file or [forwarders] that points to B or C for *.example.com domain then ?

Comment: All clients should use A, yes. A should have root hints so it has somewhere to start recursing. If `example.com` is a normal, public domain A needs no special knowledge about it, A will find it via its parents in the usual fashion. If it's a local-only domain that can't be recursed to, it needs to be pointed out in A's configuration.